# Find which process uses on average the most CPU, Memory and IO on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, memory, cpu, monitoring, io

I'd like a way to monitor processes on Windows 7 for average CPU, Memory and IO since last boot.

I would love it if it was a nice UI friendly tool that could sort processes by Average CPU, Average Memory and Average IO.

I already tried Performance Monitor, and I find it pretty terrible. Mostly, you couldn't sort the monitoring. So I'd like something else, or a way to do it with Performance Monitor.

I'm doing this to see which process uses a lot of CPU, Memory and IO so I can uninstall them.

Bonus points if the way can also show me Peaks or all process who peaked CPU 5 times since boot, etc.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try Resource Monitor instead.. it'll show you that information if you enable the right columns.

Answer (score 0):

The most advanced tool I got is Process Explorer, it has a lot of filters and all:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Answer (score 0):

Resource Monitor (resmon.exe) will display average CPU, but not since last boot. CPU, memory, and disk will be near real time. Disk Queue Length is also useful.

[image: ResMon]

[image: Disk Queue Length]

Sorry, Windows 7 is not iOS 8.

Comment: Haha, ya iOS and Android all have these measures displayed in a very clear and useful way. I'm surprised nobody made an app for Windows. It seems like such a useful thing to diagnose what is slowing your computer down.